# Is there a way to populate a data-text field in html with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, razor

Currently I have a social media plugin and you can change what it says by adding a data-text field so it will look like data-text = "something" and this works nicely but I want it to change for different pages.

I currently have set up some javascript to get the input i want and save it in a variable. Is there a way I can populate the data-text field with it?

Originally I thought to use some razor code because that will break the quotation marks and cause it to accept the razor as code and not plain text. But I was running into problems with the page not loading my razor code at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're talking about an attribute, not a field.

```
$('.my-element').attr('data-text', myVariable);
```

Comment: if I add that into my javascript and leave the data-text like this data-text="" will the javascript succesfully populate it with myVariable?

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to edit the data-text for Facebook and Linkedin? This successfully changed twitter but I don't see anything for the other two

Comment: To answer your first question, no, you don't need to add an empty attribute in your HTML. jQuery does that. As far as Facebook and LinkedIn, they may not detect dynamic changes to those elements. You may need to reload the scripts.